# Running VMware in Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vmware, rdp

I have installed a VMware application inside the Windows 10 Azure VM. Opened an 10gb OS image file using the vmware application and it says that VMware player and Hyper-V are not compatible

Comment: you should take a look at this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-vmware/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure VMs are mostly hyper-v virtual machines. From this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization#3rd-party-virtualization-apps),

> Virtualization applications other than Hyper-V are not supported in
>   Hyper-V virtual machines

So if you want to run VMware on Azure, you could use [Azure VMware Solutions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-vmware/) as @4c74356b41's comment.

> VMware Solution on Azure by CloudSimple is a fully managed service
>   that lets you run the VMware platform in Azure. This solution includes
>   vSphere, vCenter, vSAN, NSX-T, and similar tools. VMware environment
>   runs natively on Azure Bare Metal infrastructure, on Azure cloud
>   locations.

For more references, you could see this [Demo Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_uJUqy4mNk) and this [blog](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/04/run-your-vmware-natively-on-azure-with-azure-vmware-solutions/).